# How can I store array values (RLMArray) in Realm DB with Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How can I store array values (RLMArray) in Realm DB ?

My .h file below,

```
 @interface Hotlines : RLMObject
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *id;       
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *department_name;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *flag;
 @property (strong,nonatomic) RLMArray<Numbers> *numbers;   
 @end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create realm model for Numbers array:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

// Define your models for Numbers array
@interface Numbers : RLMObject
@property NSInteger *num;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Numbers) // define RLMArray< Numbers >


// Define your models for Numbers array
@interface Hotlines : RLMObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *id;       
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *department_name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *flag;
@property (strong,nonatomic) RLMArray<Numbers> *numbers;   
@end

// Implementations
@implementation Numbers
@end // none needed

@implementation Hotlines
@end // none needed
```

For more information refer [Realm Objective c](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#models)

**Update** :

```
 RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
       Hotlines *obj = [[Hotlines alloc] init]; 
       obj.department_name = @"anyString";
        Numbers *number = [[Numbers alloc] init]
        number.num = 1;
      [obj.numbers addObject:number] 
      [realm addObject:obj];
}];
```

For multiple data :

```
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    Hotlines *obj = [[Hotlines alloc] init];
    obj.department_name = @"anyString";

    for (int i=0; 1< 10; i++) {
        Numbers *number = [[Numbers alloc] init]
        number.num = i;
        number.name = @"XYZ"
        [obj.numbers addObject:number]
    }
    [realm addObject:obj];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that but I need to know how to save values for RLMArray<Numbers> *numbers:

for example:

Hotlines *obj = [[Hotlines alloc] init];
obj.department_name    = @"anyString";

obj.numbers = ????

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:obj];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

Comment: Numbers *number = [[Numbers alloc] init]
        number.num = @"1";
      [obj.numbers addObject:number] for adding number in hotline model. You can use for loop to add multiple valuses

Comment: This answer is correct. One comment -- it is probably a better idea to store the number on `Numbers` as a `NSInteger`, `double`, or `NSNumber *` type property, rather than turning it into a string.

Comment: Unfortunately I got: 'Property 'numers' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.'

Comment: @RodBaker If you reading data then you need to use  `RLMArray< Numbers > *number_array  = obj.numbers;`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with primitives if you really just want numbers:

```
@interface Hotlines : RLMObject
@property NSString *id;       
@property NSString *department_name;
@property NSString *flag;
@property RLMArray<NSNumber*><RLMFloat> *numbers;
@end
```

From the [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#many-to-many):

> RLMArrays can store primitive values in lieu of Realm objects. In
>   order to do so, constrain a RLMArray with one of the following
>   protocols: RLMBool, RLMInt, RLMFloat, RLMDouble, RLMString, RLMData,
>   or RLMDate

.